# How to disable FullCalendar navlinks when navLinks: false doesn't work?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

The page containing FullCalendar version 5.4 in my application displays (non-working) links for days and days of the week:

https://courses.ics.hawaii.edu/ics314f21/schedule/

[image: fullcalendar]

These links are created despite the fact that (by viewing the page source) you can see that I explicitly set navLinks: false:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      navLinks: false,
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      eventColor: '#446e9b',
      eventSources: [{events: moreaEventData}, holidayData]
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
</script>
```

How do I disable navLinks?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a visual feature of your theme? The headings and dates don't seem to actually do anything when you click on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion to think about the theme! I added the following CSS and now the calendar page looks better:

```
a.fc-daygrid-day-number {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.fc-col-header-cell-cushion {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```